# Nginx How remove jsession id from URL

Tags: nginx, seo

I'm using nginx with wildfly behind.

Nginx i'm using as reverse proxy and add Expires Header

When i access my static files in my browser the Expires Header is present, but when i run the SEO test on https://www.webpagetest.org, by example, the url of my static files received ;jsessionid and Expires Header Doesn'works.

How can I prevent this?

Tks

Comment: You need to fix your app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem.

After comment of Tero Kilkanen. I discover the source of problem was in Wildfly 10 server. He append ;jsessionid in links.

To solve i just add the following tag in my web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```